# Can we have login form in wcf services

Tags: asp.net

I have a set of services in my web service. every one should be authenticated before accessing any one of service. To achieve this, i want to add a login page in web service project with form authentication. is it possible?

Comment: You should either accept answers on your other questions or realize when the question is unanswerable and either delete or rewrite. That aside, If you cannot be bothered to take 2 seconds to acknowledge the time others take to help you I cannot be bothered to even consider answering your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How would a client which is another program authenticate through a form?

You should have a look at the various built in [security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734769.aspx) features that are in WCF, such as using basicHttpBinding with Windows authentication at the HTTP level.

Comment: But, A program is accessing a service. in first time of the access, i want to authenticate the request. so, i want to redirect to a login page where i can validate the request. This is what i want to do.

I know that client program can pass the authentication ticket to service based on that we can allow.